# Code not throwing exception a second time, though program doesn't halt

Tags: java

I have a question regarding a class constructor not throwing a second exception.

I currently have three classes; one class as a demo, one class with a constructor that handles a double array, and a third exception class.

If the program receives a test score below 0 or over 100, the program should throw an exception. I have the first element of the array being passed as -1, which is handled as expected. The 4th element, however, is 101. The program doesn't halt and the result is correct, however the exception message is not given a second time.

Here is the constructor for the test class:

```
public Test(double[] scores) throws InvalidScore {

    testScores = new double[scores.length];

    for (int index = 0; index < scores.length; index++) {

        if (scores[index] < 0 || scores[index] > 100) {

            throw new InvalidScore("Element: " + index + "\nInvalid 
            score: " + scores[index]);

        }

        if (scores[index >= 0 && scores[index] <= 100) {

            testScores[index] = scores[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies if the formatting is off. Below is the array I am passing to this constructor.

```
double badScores = {-1, 97.5, 66.7, 88.0, 101.0, 99.0};
```

If possible, it would be preferable to just be pointed in the direction of where this has gone wrong. I've read and re-read my constructors logic but I think I'm getting tunnel vision now. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Uh, once it throws an Exception, it already left the class, there's no way to continue from there.

Comment: Oh lord. Yes, it does, thank you. I was focusing on the class that was iterating through the scores, not the class that was actually calling it. Thank you for taking the time to comment.